# javascript error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'element')

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run the following code:

```
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body"));
js.executeScript("var injector = window.angular.element(argument[0]).injector(); var $http = injector.get('$http'); return ($http.pendingRequests.length === 0);",body);
```

I however get the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'element')
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)
Build info: version: '4.2.2', revision: '683ccb65d6'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-UPVJF2U', ip: '192.168.0.132', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.1.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [c6b4ce36aa115d9746065cead6c3271b, executeScript {script=var injector = window.angular.element(argument[0]).injector(); var $http = injector.get('$http'); return ($http.pendingRequests.length === 0);, args=[{ELEMENT=a0c33e06-9db9-49ed-984f-535b6bc72f7a, element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf=a0c33e06-9db9-49ed-984f-535b6bc72f7a}]}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 103.0.5060.134, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 103.0.5060.134 (8ec6fce403b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\win10\AppData\Loca...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:53279}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:53279/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 103.0.5060.134, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: c6b4ce36aa115d9746065cead6c3271b
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:167)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:588)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:522)
    at com.vilcart.app.CustomerCreation.testCreation(CustomerCreation.java:118)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
... Removed 28 stack frames
```

Can you please let me know how i could resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to get `arguments` list element by index try to replace

```
argument[0]
```

with

```
arguments[0]
```

Comment: i get the same error, My bad i used argument[0] instead of arguments[0] but the above problem hasn't been solved. The same error keeps coming.

Comment: @suhailshaik did you try `angular.element(...)` instead of `window.angular.element(...)`?

Comment: i just tried, i get the error < javascript error: angular is not defined>.

Answer (score 0):

@suhail shaik You can try the following, assuming you want to check if all the pending $http requests are served by Angular in the background.

```
  String angularReady = "return angular.element(document).injector().get('$http').pendingRequests.length === 0";

  boolean isAngularReady = (boolean)js.executeScript(angularReady);
```

Comment: yes i want to proceed further in the code only if all the pending $http requests are  finished. But i am getting "javascript error: angular is not defined" after running you code at line  "boolean isAngularReady = (boolean)js.executeScript(angularReady);  "

Comment: @suhail shaik Is you application is in public domain then I can try and see what is causing it

Comment: you can download my code from here https://github.com/suhailsqm/FirstTestNG.git It;s a repo in github, Basically i am logging into a website and trying to put wait before i check it's title. Please kindly have a look, if you could spare some time.

Comment: @suhail shaik seems your app is not loading the angular libraries and hence you are getting this message. Ideally, in an angular app, you will find the following in <head>  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>. You might want to check with developer about this.

Comment: I added the following <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.min.js"></script> in my code, Now i am facing an error <javascript error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')>. I googled if i could find the latest version of angular google api. This is the latest i could find. even if angular exist it seems that injector doesn't exist. Our developer says no need to add angular google api.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through this link which helped me find a solution. This has a way to put wait for angular version 5 which is working for my current angular version 11.
https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-wait-javascript-angular-ajax/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).